# Python PyQt5 All text in QTextBrowser becomes 'hyperactive'

Tags: python-3.x, url, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I have a problem with text in QTextBrowser. I have a similar code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.textBox = QTextBrowser(centralWidget)

        self.textBox.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.button = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.button.setText("PUSH")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.pressed)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textBox)

    def pressed(self):
        id = 49309034
        url_name = "test_link"
        link = '<a href = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{0}> {1} </a>'.format(id, url_name)
        dict = {'Key': 'Value', link: 'Test link'}
        for key, value in dict.items():
            self.textBox.append('{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
        self.textBox.append("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So, when I push button I get:
[image]

However, if I click on the link and then push button again - all text becomes 'hyperactive':
[image]

I  think, the problem is in 'next line'. Because I've tried such code and it's working properly:

```
string = ""
for key, value in dict.items():
    string += '{0}: {1}'.format(key, value) + '; '
self.textBox.append(string)
```

[image]

After I've clicked on the URL and pushed button
[image]

Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: What do you mean by all text becomes 'hyperactive'. Only 'test link' is being displayed as hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the cursor before adding lines to QTextBrowser.
For example, like this:

```
self.textBox.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Start)
```

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.textBox = QTextBrowser(centralWidget)

        self.textBox.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.button = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.button.setText("PUSH")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.pressed)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textBox)

    def pressed(self):

        self.textBox.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Start)       # <---

        id = 49309034
        url_name = "test_link"
        link = '<a href = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{0}> {1} </a>'.format(id, url_name)
        dict = {'Key': 'Value', link: 'Test link'}
        for key, value in dict.items():
            self.textBox.append('{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
        self.textBox.append("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking about this problem for so long.

Comment: is more readable: `self.textBox.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Start)`